# How can i control firefox (started on remote pc with opt -no-remote)?

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, ssh

The task: 
Log into another pc with ssh and start firefox from there (options -no-remote). Then do some actions in it.

I use python+selenium, but i dont know how to control remote firefox.
Anyone can help me?

===================================================================

On Russian
Задача - залогиниться на другую машину и открыть с нее удаленный firefox с параметрами -no-remote. Потом нужно с помощью селениума сделать в интерфейсе несколько действий.

Пользоваться желательно с помощью питона и селениума. 
Есть ли у кого нибудь какие-нибудь предложения?

UPD 21.11.14:
I installed python+selenium on remote pc. I moved some code which controls firefox there.
I looked up for examples and got this one:

```
def testfunc():
    cmd="python2.7 BIND.py" # Remote test
    result = commands.getoutput(cmd)

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname=mil_ws, username=user, password=secret, port=portSSH)
t = client.get_transport ()  
chan = t.open_session ()  
chan.request_x11 (handler=testfunc())  
chan.set_combine_stderr (True)  
bufsize = -1  
stdin = chan.makefile('wb', bufsize)  
stdout = chan.makefile('rb', bufsize)  
stderr = chan.makefile_stderr('rb', bufsize)  
client.close()
```

The problem is that script runs firefox on my machine instead of on remote. If i started BIND.py on remote xterm - firefox started on correctly.
How can i start remote firefox with my main test?

P.S. Sry for my bad english

Comment: Duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9107/how-can-i-run-firefox-on-linux-headlessly-i-e-without-requiring-libgtk-x11-2-0

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev i dont see the solution there. I need specific way to start firefox remotely. I have a working script which works correctly if i start it manually using ssh connection.But if i use paramiko firefox starts on my pc not on the remote one. I'm looking for some configuration option for selenium config or something like that.

Comment: How do you start firefox? I cannot see it in the code provided.

Comment: There's no need to post questions in two languages; Stack Overflow is an English-language site, so anyone one here should either be able to speak English or have a translator handy anyway. It makes the post more confusing to have it written in two languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Selenium Remote Control](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/) appears to be the product to host remote test sessions.

Comment: Yeah thx. It helps me. My solution: 
1) Start Selenium Server on remote PC 
2) Browser invocation code:
`browser = webdriver.Remote( desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX, command_executor='http://%s:4444/wd/hub' %remote_pc)`